# Show that a space is not locally connected

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, limits, connectedness

> Let $X=\{0\}\cup\{\frac{1}{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Establish if $X$ is locally connected.

I think that $X$ is not locally connected. In fact, $\{0\}$ is a connected component because if I take a set $A$ that contains $\{0\}$ and other elements, then there exists $n_{1}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n_{1}}\in A$. Now, for example, $A=[(-1,\frac{1}{n_{1}+0,5})\cap X ]\sqcup [(\frac{1}{n_{1}+0,5},2)\cap X]$, hence $A$ is not connected.
$\{0\}$ it's also a limit point so if I take a neighborhood $U$ of $\{0\}$, then the only possible connected subset is $\{0\}$ itself. But $\{0\}$ is not open so I proved what I wanted.
Is this right?

Comment: You haven't proven it unless you have proven that $\{0\}$ is indeed a component. Please show us your proof of this too, if you want a proper verification

Comment: I edited my question. Can you give me a feedback please? Thanks before

Comment: The part '{0}  it's also a limit point so if I take a neighborhood U of {0}, then the only possible connected subset is {0} itself' is strange. I thought that the fact that the only possible connected subset having $0$ is $\{0\}$ you got in the previous part. I would remove the part  '{0}  it's also a limit point so if I take a neighborhood U of {0}, '.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs at $0$.  It doesn't have a connected neighborhood.

Proof:

Let $\mathscr U$ be a neighborhood of $0$.  Take $n$ such that $1/n\in\mathscr U$.  Then $\mathscr U=\mathscr U\setminus \{1/n\}\cup\{1/n\}$ is a disconnection of $\mathscr U$.